# In context menu in list, string is too long and gets cut off

Tags: android, contextmenu

In my app I use a context menu for a list of items. 
When the string is too long to fit, it doesnt break or anything, just cuts off. 
Any suggestions on what I can do to fix this?

Best regards,
Anders
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My comment was not meant to be entirely facetious... but I believe it is the only simple way to deal with this problem.

The more involved way that might work would be to create your own context menu, but that is probably more trouble than it is worth. Something like this http://www.anddev.org/creating_a_contextmenu_on_a_listview-t2438.html